# Unique string constraint with Ruby-on-rails and GraphQL mutations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I've been searching documentation but I don't see anything regarding unique constraints in GraphQL with Ruby.

How can you enforce a unique constraint on a string that you want to pass through a mutation?

```
module Types
  class PersonType < Types::BaseObject
    field :name, String, null:false
  end
end
```

I've tried adding ", unique: true" to the field, but it doesn't recognize the keyword unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the unique constraint rule on the resolver of the mutation:

```
const resolvers={
...

    Mutation:{
      someField:async(parent,{name},context)=>{
          if(name === 'something'){
              return context.dataSource.createUser(....)
          }else(e){
               throw new Error("This name is not allowed")
                  }
          }
      }
    }
```